# Play Ebean does not generate Id after upgrading from 2.4 to 2.5

Tags: java, playframework, h2, ebean, playframework-2.5

I am currently in the process of upgrading my application's play from 2.4.x to 2.5.18. By play's doc, I also upgraded play-ebean from 1.0.0 to 3.2.0, which uses ebean 10.4.x. After upgrading, whenever I insert a bean into the h2 database it gives this error:

`[DataIntegrityException: Error[NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement: insert into users (email, name, first_name, last_name, last_login, active, email_validated) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [23502-185]]]`

It seems ebean is not generating an id for the newly inserted bean. I will not encounter the error when I set the id manually before saving (`user.id = 123`). However, I really want id generation to work again.

Versions:

- play 2.5.18
- play-ebean 3.2.0
- h2 database 1.4.185
- deadbolt 2.5.6
- java 1.8.0 update 151

In plugins.sbt

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.2.0")`

In build.sbt

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean).settings(libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaCore,
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  evolutions,
  javaWs
)
```

In application.conf

`ebean.default = ["models.*"]`

This is a model that stores user's information. It also implements deadbolt's Subject. I quadruple-checked that I am not overriding save in the model.

```
package models;
...
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends AppModel implements Subject {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Email
    public String email;

    public String name;

    public String firstName;

    public String lastName;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public Date lastLogin;

    public boolean active;

    public boolean emailValidated;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Mapping> mappings;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<DbConn> dbconns;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<OntoFile> ontofiles;

    @ManyToMany
    public List<SecurityRole> roles;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<LinkedAccount> linkedAccounts;

    @ManyToMany
    public List<UserPermission> permissions;

    public static final Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder<Long, User>(User.class);

    ...

    public static User create(final AuthUser authUser) {
        final User user = new User();
        user.roles = Collections.singletonList(SecurityRole
                .findByRoleName(controllers.Application.USER_ROLE));
        user.active = true;
        user.lastLogin = new Date();
        user.linkedAccounts = Collections.singletonList(LinkedAccount
                .create(authUser));

        if (authUser instanceof EmailIdentity) {
            final EmailIdentity identity = (EmailIdentity) authUser;
            user.email = identity.getEmail();
            user.emailValidated = false;
        }

        if (authUser instanceof NameIdentity) {
            final NameIdentity identity = (NameIdentity) authUser;
            final String name = identity.getName();
            if (name != null) {
                user.name = name;
            }
        }

        if (authUser instanceof FirstLastNameIdentity) {
          final FirstLastNameIdentity identity = (FirstLastNameIdentity) authUser;
          final String firstName = identity.getFirstName();
          final String lastName = identity.getLastName();
          if (firstName != null) {
            user.firstName = firstName;
          }
          if (lastName != null) {
            user.lastName = lastName;
          }
        }

        user.save(); // error happens here
        Ebean.save(user); // this does not work either
        return user;
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't know why this exists, but previous guys who wrote this app put it there and it never caused any problem, so I am leaving it there for now. In addition,  extending User to Model instead of AppModel does not fix the error.

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import io.ebean.Model;

@MappedSuperclass
public class AppModel extends Model
{}
```

I also tried configuring the ebean server. Both id generator and packages are empty. I added models to the list but error still occurs. Could this mean ebean is not configured properly?

```
package models;
...
public class MyServerConfigStartup implements ServerConfigStartup {
    public void onStart(ServerConfig serverConfig) {
        List<IdGenerator> gen = serverConfig.getIdGenerators();
        System.out.println(gen); // []

        List<String> pack1 = serverConfig.getPackages();
        System.out.println(pack1); // []
        ArrayList<String> packages = new ArrayList<String>();
        packages.add("models.*");
        serverConfig.setPackages(packages);
        List<String> pack2 = serverConfig.getPackages();
        System.out.println(pack2); // [models.*]
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the id columns in the h2 database need to have auto_increment now. Running `ALTER TABLE name ALTER COLUMN colName bigint not null auto_increment` on all tables fixes this issue.